# XCode 12.2/Big Sur: Where are the object inspector and SwiftUI library?

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I don't know how to accurately phrase this, but after upgrading to Big Sur and XCode 12.2, I have discovered that I cannot Command-Click on a SwiftUI keyword (i.e., `HStack` or `TextField`) and get the object-specific inspector to come up. On my right panel I only ever see the inspector/settings for the .swift source file I have open; how do I get the object-specific context menu to come back?

Another issue, probably related to the first: when pressing the "+" button to insert a new object from the library, there are no longer any SwiftUI library objects available to pick; see the screenshot below:

[[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 2):

The Canvas Editor must be open, and then everything works.